# Time Series Changing Values

Tags: r

so I wanted to forecast month-over-month increases for four columns to the end of the year; however, upon creating my dataset through ts, it removed the value of my imported dataset. Is there a reason for this that I can avoid? Or should it have come out in such a manner.

```
Month - 2022-03-01, 2022-04-01,2022-05-01,2022-06-01,2022-07-01
Visits- 71893, 40683,32455,34898,49834
Revenue- 87036,23846,34575,39732,45632
Orders- 3488,6578,4345,5644,6543
Conversion Rate- .35%,.33%,.43%,.39%
```

However, it is returning the following below: does this have an actual meaning? Or is the month column causing this?

```
 Month - 2022-03-01, 2022-04-01,2022-05-01,2022-06-01,2022-07-01
Visits- 5,1,2,3,4
Revenue- 5,3,4,1,2
Orders- 1,2,3,4,5
Conversion Rate- 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Seems like several columns of your input data is maybe `character` or `factor` class and should be `numeric`? Definitely if you have `%` signs in your data it is non-numeric.

Comment: If you use dput() https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput to add your data, it will help people identify the problem.